# Convert CSS cubic bezier easing to Javascript

Tags: javascript, tween, easing

I'm looking for a way to generate easing functions for my tweens, I need them in Javascript function format, with the standard `t, b, c, d` parameters.

I've found a great tool to generate CSS easing: http://cubic-bezier.com/ but the output is useless to me.

- **Is there a way to convert this format to a Javascript easing function?**
- **Are there any better tools to directly build Javascript easing functions?**

---

The desired format is something like:

```
function(t, b, c, d){
    var ts = (t /= d) * t;
    var tc = ts * t;
    return b+c*(4.257575757575761*tc*ts + -7.9545454545454595*ts*ts + 0.6818181818181834*tc + 4.46969696969697*ts + -0.4545454545454546*t);
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is library for Bezier Curve based easing in JavaScript  https://github.com/gre/bezier-easing

You could just select desired parameters from 
http://cubic-bezier.com
and pass them to function BezierEasing.
For example:

```
BezierEasing(0.25, 0.1, 0.0, 1.0)
```

Here is a example from documentation:

https://jsfiddle.net/0x51ew2L/

Comment: Thanks for the rewrite. Always horrible when they make it specific (for node). However does not work for negative values, but I guess I can convert after.

Comment: Is there a cdn for this?

Answer (score -1):

Like so:

```
element = document.getElementById('targetElement');
element.style.transitionTimingFunction = 'cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275)';
```

Comment: this does not answer the OP's original question on converting css cubic bezier easing to javascript, not using css cubic bezier